# Возможно ли установить timeout для Socket

Tags: java, сокет, javafx, клиент-сервер, timeout

Всем привет!
У меня десктопное приложение на javafx клиент-сервер.
Схема такова: преподаватель - клиент, студенты - сервер.
Так вот мой клиент опрашивает всех студентов по списку, установлен setSoTimeout() и все бы хорошо, только вот проблема в том что когда машина студента выключена подключение к этой машине осуществляется достаточно долго и по итогу исключение:

```
java.net.UnknownHostException
```

все понятно, что к чему. И мой вопрос заключается вот в чем можно ли как-то осуществить проверку на существование такого хоста с указанием timeout да бы ускорить процесс опроса машин.

Comment: Чем пользуетесь для конекта? Покажите код хотя бы.

Comment: `Socket clientSocket = new Socket();        
        clientSocket.connect(new InetSocketAddress(address, port), timeout);`

Comment: Пробовал еще:
`InetAddress.getByName(listMachine.getName()).isReachable(timeout);`
но он опять же нормально работает только если хост существует

Comment: А почему преподаватель - не сервер?

Comment: Изначально так я так и думал сделать, но взвесив все за и против была выбрана данная модель поведения.